# Attach default cache to angular ngResource calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I can't find a way to do this so I'm not sure it's currently possible without doing some serious monkey patching with the $decorator service, but I would love to set a default cache (true, false, some instance of $cacheFactory) to my ngResource definitions.  I know for any custom actions on the resource you define you can add a cache:(value) property, but can you do it in general for each RESTful call generated using $resource?